# Can I run Powershell commands as admin in PSSession when logged in as other user?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, remote-access

*Scenario:*

Normally, I would use remote desktop, log on to my server, launch the Powershell window as Administrator and perform the import-module and subsequent commands to get the information I'm looking for. When I log on using remote desktop, I don't log on as Administrator, but I do log on as a user that belongs to the Administrators group. (I don't have the Admin creds.)

*Question:*

I can easily create a session using New-PSSession. I can enter this session using Enter-PSSession. After I've entered the session, I import the module I need to use. After I import the module, I attempt to run a command from that module. I do get some output, but I also get "[Get-WmiObject], UnauthorizedAccessException". I do not get this error when I log on to the server with remote desktop and launch the powershell window as Administrator. Is there a way I can do this with a PSSession?

Comment: Is your Get-WmiObject Cmdlet use -computername to request information from a third computer ?

Comment: Looks like it is yes. This is the command inside the function I'm calling: "Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $item". The purpose of this function is to get the available memory on our 3 Hyper-V blades.

Comment: So I met your trouble before.

Answer (score 3):

I met such a problem and it was due to the *Forwarding of credentials in multihop environments*.

Using New-PSSession you only have a network token on the second computer, you can’t directly connect to another computer.

The interactive token, I mean what you get when you sit down in front of a PC and log on (or using TS) is required to automatically connect to another computer, and to create an interactive token, the user’scredentials are needed.

To accomplish the interactive credential forwarding magic, PowerShell uses a mechanism called CredSSP (Credential Security Service Provider).

CredSSP need to be allowed on both side. You have to run these commands from an elevated PowerShell
session.

To allow CredSSP on the client side run :

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role client -DelegateComputer computername
```

To allow CredSSP on the server side run :

```
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role server
```

You've got a good explanation in [Chapter 13. Remoting: configuring applications and services](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781935182139/firstchapter?reader=html&imagepage=#X2ludGVybmFsX0ZsYXNoUmVhZGVyP3htbGlkPTk3ODE5MzUxODIxMzkvY2gxMw==)